# Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0, 1]^2$ with $m_2(A) = 1$, where $m_2$ is two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Show that $m(s_x(A))=1$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0, 1]^2$
with $m_2(A) = 1$, where $m_2$ is two-dimensional Lebesgue measure.
Show that for almost every $x \in [0, 1]$ (with respect to one dimensional
Lebesgue measure) the set $s_x(A)$ (this means the section at $x$) has one-dimensional
Lebesgue measure one.

Is this not a false statement? Obvious counterexamples are rectangles that are $r \times \dfrac{1}{r}$ in dimension.

Comment: Your rectangle is not in $[0,1]^2$

Comment: I’m not sure I follow your logic with the “obvious counterexamples” you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting that $A$ is contained in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. So your example doesn't work.

Since $0 \leq m(s_x(A))\leq 1$ and $\int m(s_x(A))dx=m(A)=1$ by Fubini's Theorem it follows that $m(s_x(A))=1$ a.e.. [$1-m(s_x(A))$ is non-negative measurable function whose integral is $0$ so the function is $0$ a.e..]

Comment: Ohhh yeah. I misread it